# Python dataframe cross multiply

Tags: python, dataframe

please see the link to answer , appreciated
dataframe has 2 columns ID and Name

Name has array
whats needed is to cross multiply  column I Dto Name

and expected result shown in the image link provided

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Lets use `df.explode` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','C'],'Name':[['A','B','C'],['C','D'],['A']]})
df.explode('Name')
```

```
  ID Name
0  A    A
0  A    B
0  A    C
1  B    C
1  B    D
2  C    A
```